# Laravel: Auth::user()->role_id in app.blade.php display Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

In my users table I add `role_id` column where 1 is `admin` and 2 is `user`. So, when I want to his page in header in my **app.blade.php** file like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   @if(Auth::user()->role_id == 1)
    <li><a href="{!! url('/admin/users'); !!}">Users</a></li>
   @endif
</ul>
```

error appear:
(3/3) ErrorException
The use statement with non-compound name 'Auth' has no effect (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\vendetta\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\vendetta\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)

index() method in AdminUsersController looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Role;
use App\Http\Requests\UserCreateRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UserUpdateRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Auth;


class AdminUsersController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::paginate(5);

        if(Auth::user()->role_id !== 1) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));
    }
```

When I use `check()` instead of `user()->role_id == 1`, It works but then all users can see except one that not login, but I want to see only `admin`.

I cannot find the answer in similar topics...

Comment: You have some use statement in **app.blade.php** you can remove it and use `auth()->user()->role_id` instead.

Comment: try this code ```@if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role_id == 1)``` and let me know result

Comment: Thanks @Mohammadb   `if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role_id == 1)` works fine.

Comment: @shone83 good , I post my comment as answer , its my pleasure to accept it as answer of your question

Answer (score 1):

you use

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   @if(Auth::user()->role_id == 1)
    <li><a href="{!! url('/admin/users'); !!}">Users</a></li>
   @endif
</ul>
```

but you are not sure the user logged in or not

I mean maybe user is guest and not logged in

you should use

```
@if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role_id == 1)
```

this condition check user is looged in then check user role_id

so replace code with:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role_id == 1)
    <li><a href="{!! url('/admin/users'); !!}">Users</a></li>
   @endif
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in your index() method in AdminUsersController:

```
 public function __construct()
 {
     // user must log in to use this controller
     $this->middleware('auth');        
 }

 public function index()
 {
    $users = User::paginate(5);

    if(Auth::check()){
       $roldId = Auth::user()->role_id;
       if($roldId !== 1) {
           return redirect('/home');
       }
    }   

    return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));
 }
```

It works for me and I hope it will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely getting this error because `Auth::user()` is `NULL` as no user is logged in when you visit that route.

Try adding the below to your controller to ensure that only logged in users can use the AdminUsers controller.

```
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    // user must log in to use this controller
    $this->middleware('auth');        
}
```

Whenever a user tries to visit one of the routes managed by this controller, s/he will be asked to login first. Then your `Auth::user()->role_id == 1` will not return this error.

Reference: [Laravel - protecting routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#protecting-routes)